# System.Environment.Version returns different results on OS X

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and having trouble returning from an external DLL call. This code has worked previously, so I'm unsure what has changed. I am using Unity 4.3.4 on OS X 10.9. The one thing I noticed is that when I run System.Environment.Version.ToString() in the editor, I get 2.0.50727.1433 but when I build the project and run it outside Unity I get 3.0.40818.0. Any ideas why these are so different and what I can do about it?

Comment: It would depend on the framework that the host uses (I assume Unity is a "host").  If you run it under a host that uses 3.0.40818.0, you'll get 3.0.40818.0...

Comment: Please check my tag edit unity->unity3d: assuming you are talking about Unity3d (game platform), not Unity (DI container).

Comment: Thank you for editing the tag. I am talking about Unity3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to match the version numbers by setting my Player Settings API Compatibility Level to .NET 2.0. It was previously set as .NET 2.0 subset.